# Make Python code more efficient for reducing script size?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, grovepi+

[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNMj7.jpg)I am new to Python and trying to make my code more efficient. Currently I am pushing sensor values to Firebase Realtime database into different fields, but the code is repetitive. Is there anyway I can  reduce the size of the script by using a loop or an alternative method.

```
def getSound():
    sound_value = grovepi.analogRead(sound_sensor)
    result = firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/'{'Sound1':int(sound_value)})
    print("the sound value is%d" %sound_value)
    time.sleep(1)

def getSound1():
    sound_value = grovepi.analogRead(sound_sensor)
    result = firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/'{'Sound2':int(sound_value)})
    print("the sound value is%d" %sound_value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Write a function that takes anything that's different between those two functions as a parameter.

Comment: Can you elaborate thank you

Comment: I assume there is a comma missing: it should be `firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/', {'Sound1':int(sound_value)})`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Change the function so that it accepts the sound number as a parameter:

```
def getSound(number):
    sound_value = grovepi.analogRead(sound_sensor)
    key = 'Sound%d' % number # this will be 'Sound1', 'Sound2', etc.
    result = firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/'{key :int(sound_value)})
    print("the sound value is%d" %sound_value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then you would call the function as `getSound(1)`, `getSound(2)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am getting the following error


 result = firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/'{key :int(sound_value)})
                                                  ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I thought that looked odd, but I copied it from your original code, so I assumed it worked.  Did you actually run the code you posted?

Comment: What is the argument to `firebase.patch()` supposed to be?  Is it just a plain string, like `'/SoundValues/Monday/Sound1'`?

Comment: I'm trying to run the sound sensor value and store each value in Firebase and not overwrite it  for example I want 10 values in Firebase and these will be stored from sound1 to sound10

Comment: Okay, but what is the argument to `patch()` supposed to be?  Do you have an example?  I don't know anything about firebase.

Comment: I have posted the full code above at the start of the question as (Updated code)

Answer (score 0):

I would always look at what is different between getSound() and getSound1().
Looks like the functions have the exact same code, except for this line:

```
result = firebase.patch('/SoundValues/Monday/'{'Sound1':int(sound_value)})
```

So you can write a single function with the all the repetitive code and use 'sound_spec' as a parameter to your function. It would look something like:

```
sound_value = grovepi.analogRead(sound_sensor)

def getSound(sound_spec):
    result = firebase.patch(sound_spec)
    print("the sound value is%d" %sound_value)
    print("firebase.path result %s" % str(result))
    time.sleep(1)
```

You could then have a list of 'sound_specification' and use a for loop to get the result for multiple values:

```
sound_specs = ['/SoundValues/Monday/'{'Sound1':int(sound_value)},'/SoundValues/Monday/'{'Sound2':int(sound_value)}]

for sound_spec in sound_specs:
    getSound(sound_spec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I am getting a name error for sound_value: 
NameError: name 'sound_value' is not defined

Comment: can you please post your entire code, including the 'firebase' code?

Comment: I have included an image through a link above at the beginning of the question (Updated code)

Comment: i just updated my answer. The 'sound_value' needed to defined before the 'getSound()' function so that the function as well as 'sound_specs' can access it. I  also updated the code inside the 'getSound()' function so it also prints the 'result' from firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I am now getting the following error :

TypeError: patch() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

Comment: It seems like the 'patch' function is requiring more parameters, please post the 'patch' function code from firebase.